# Could not read state file "obj\Debug\Helpers.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache" error when publishing project

Tags: .net, publish, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to publish an ASP.NET website and got the following warning:
`Could not read state file "obj\Debug\Helpers.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache"`

This prevents me from actually publishing the website. Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple: first clean the whole solution and then publish again. Now everything should work.

The problem was due to the fact that the state file was in an older format (VS2012 RC format) and I was trying to publish from VS2012 RTM.

Comment: I was getting this on loads of our VS2010 projects after installing VS2012, which was worrying for a bit! The solution was the same as yours - do a clean build. In our case, we just passed the "Rebuild" parameter to our MSBuild project file to do a clean build of everything, i.e. we specified the following parameter to MSBuild: /p:"Targets=Rebuild"

Comment: Clean/rebuild is the standard thing to do if you run into weird building errors :-)

Comment: After BSODing in middle of build, was getting this all over the place. Clean build fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

just exclude "Obj\Debug" folder.Rebuild project and host.

Comment: Clean and build didn't work for me on VS2017. Though excluding ...obj\debug folder from the project, rebuild and then publish worked well.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to delete the project and create a new one, then it will work.

Comment: That seems a bit less simple than clean and rebuild, no?

Answer (score 0):

I do not doubt that for some, the answer may be as simple as cleaning the solution and rebuilding. However, for me, that was not the case.

The problem in my case was that I have two different versions of Visual Studio installed, and the version of MSBuild that I was using was accidentally different from the version of NuGet that I was using.

So, make sure that you are using both NuGet and MSBuild from the same installation of Visual Studio.